# When does a Markov chain not have a steady state?

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

I was asked this question on an oral qual, and eventually I seemed to conclude that there have to be eigenvalues of modulus 1.  But I just realised *every* Markov matrix has one as an eigenvalue.  So should the condition be multiple eigenvalues with modulus 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. If $P$ is a Markov transition matrix, then $P^n$ converges 
as $n\to\infty$ if and only if $P$'s only eigenvalue of modulus one is $\lambda=1.$

Comment: Note that $p_0 P^n$ may converge even when $P^n$ does not.

Comment: @Ian Sure! The set of limits of $p_0 P^n$ over all probability vectors $p_0$ equals the set of invariant probability vectors, which is non-empty.

Answer (score 11):

Every Markov chain on a finite state space has an invariant distribution. As you said, this follows directly from the condition that the rows sum to $1$.

It is possible for a Markov chain on a finite state space to have multiple invariant distributions. However, the Perron-Frobenius theorem tells us that these can be decomposed into distributions which are concentrated on strongly connected components of the state space. Decomposing the process into strongly connected components results in one or more different Markov chains each of which has a unique invariant distribution.

Any transient states of the original chain will not be states in any of these sub-chains, since they are not in any strongly connected component. Confusingly, this means that a chain that is not irreducible is generically not reducible into chains on disjoint subsets of the state space. That's because generically some transient states would have to be in more than one sub-chain, which is because generically one can reach more than one strongly connected component starting from a transient state.

As an important special case, an irreducible finite state Markov chain has a unique invariant distribution which assigns positive probability to all states.

However many invariant distributions the process has, it can happen that no invariant distribution is approached over time. When the state space is finite, it turns out that this only happens when the chain is "periodic" (meaning that there are states $i,j$ and an integer $n>1$ such that all paths from $i$ to $j$ have a length which is a multiple of $n$). In this case the transition matrix has an eigenvalue which is not $1$ and has modulus $1$. If the corresponding eigenvector contributes to the initial condition, then its contribution does not decay, and no invariant distribution is approached. The classic example of a periodic chain is $P=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, but in general it is not essential that the chain is deterministic for it to be periodic.

It is possible for a Markov chain on an infinite state space to not have any invariant distributions. This is roughly because probability mass can escape to infinity. A simple example is a Markov chain on $\mathbb{Z}$ which deterministically moves one unit to the right at every step. Another example is the simple symmetric random walk: it has an invariant *measure* which is uniform on $\mathbb{Z}$, but this measure cannot be normalized.

Comment: "A Markov chain on an infinite state space can have no invariant distribution." - I would reword this, because it can easily be interpreted as "no Markov chain on an infinite state space can have an invariant distribution" which is clearly not true.

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks. I don't like the flow of the new sentence, but I see the issue.

Comment: That is how I interpreted the sentence when I read it and I was very confused at first :)

Comment: So, is it true that a finite-state Markov chain with no unique equilibrium distribution must have multiple eigenvalues with modulus one?

Comment: @TorsionSquid A finite-state Markov chain with multiple invariant distributions has an eigenvalue of $1$ with a geometric multiplicity higher than $1$. Any eigenvalues which are not $1$, regardless of their modulus, are not relevant to the question of existence, only to the question of the long term limit. (Also, I would suggest you stick to the word "invariant" rather than "equilibrium" if there is a possibility that the invariant distribution is not approached. Math people will not get confused, but stat mech people might.)

Comment: +1 This is an excellent answer that provides a lot of information. I suspect that what the OP means by "steady state" is not an invariant measure, but rather the convergence of $P^n$. I've added a short answer as a companion to yours.

Comment: +1 also for the last comment....and thank you very much for my recent question.